# Semi-Interquartile Range and Asymmetry Coefficient

Tags: descriptive-statistics, interquartile

What is the amplitude of a semi-interquartile distribution of a moderately asymmetrical distribution whose standard deviation value is 1?

I know that the definition of the requested amplitude is $A_{si} = \frac{Q_3 - Q_1}{2}$ and I also know that a moderately asymmetric distribution has $0.15 < |A_p| < 1$ on what $A_p = \frac{\bar{X} - \hat{m}_0}{S_X}$ (Pearson's Asymmetry Coefficient).

Is it possible to reach an answer through these disciplines? Since the curve is moderately asymmetrical, does the question leave a relaxation? Or is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: Solving which problem?